# In my React application, when I query the database for a link. Instead of the link, it returns the index.html file in the public folder

Tags: reactjs, mysql-workbench

I am building a React application and I have placeholder images that I am using for all the pages of the application. I created a database that currently only holds an ID (primary key), a code (for pulling the specific images for a specific page), and a path (containing a url to each image stored on my machine). My images are currently not showing on the page and I am trying to get one page to show the images and then duplicate that work for the others. I have created my connection, set up my routes, and my query's. Using fetch to pull the image urls from the database that match the code for that page is returning the index.html file from my public folder so of course I am getting an error message saying my result is not valid JSON. I found that out through researching the problem and changing the code so I could see what was happening. Now I am lost as to why it is happening and dont know how to fix it. I am including some files below:

So each page of the app is supposed to have the actual text to appear on the page and some placeholder images that will be replaced with photos relevant to the content. This was actually working when I first set this up a few months ago but I had a problem with mysql and had to delete it and reinstall and since I expected this to be a simple process since its a tiny database, I didnt save it and am now trying to make it work again.

```
Index.js file that holds the routes:
```

```
import express from "express";
import cards from '../db/queries/cards'
import customers from '../db/queries/customers'


const router = express.Router();

router.get("/test", (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ msg: "Hello World!" });
});



router.get("/cards/:code?", async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        let {code} = req.params;
   
        let imageURL = await cards.getRealCards(code);
    
      res.status(200).json(imageURL);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
}
});
router.get("/cards/:code?", async (req, res, next) => {
  try{
      let {code} = req.params;
 
      let imageURL = await cards.getCalendarCards(code);
  
    res.status(200).json(imageURL);
  } catch (error) {
      next(error);
  }
});
router.get("/cards/:code?", async (req, res, next) => {
  try{
      let {code} = req.params;
 
      let imageURL = await cards.getHolidayCards(code);
  
    res.status(200).json(imageURL);
  } catch (error) {
      next(error);
  }
});
router.post("/insert", async (req,res,next) => {
  try{
    let response = await customers.insertCustomer(req.body)
    res.json(response); 
  }catch(error){
    next(error);
 }  
});



export default router;
```

```
database is called mrpostcard and the table is called cards...this is the cards.js file:
```

```
    const { Query } = require("./db/models");

    const getRealCards = () => {
        return Query("SELECT * FROM  cards WHERE code = 100")
    };
    const getCalenderCards = () => {
        return Query("SELECT * FROM  cards WHERE code = 200")
    };

    const getSportsCards = () => {
        return Query("SELECT * FROM  cards WHERE code = 300")
    };

    const getHolidayCards = () => {
        return Query("SELECT * FROM  cards WHERE code = 400")
    };

    const getBusinessCards = () => {
        return Query("SELECT * FROM  cards WHERE code = 500")
    };

    module.exports = {
        getRealCards,
        getCalenderCards,
        getSportsCards,
        getHolidayCards,
        getBusinessCards,
    };
```

the page I am trying to get the pics to show on is called RealEstate.js and is where the error is happening there are 2 fetch blocks here, the second fetch block that is commented out is the original code I used to get the images through my online search, I found the code for the first fetch block and refactored it to work with my code and found what I was actually getting back:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import FadeIn from "react-fade-in";

    export default class RealEstate extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          postcards: []
        }
      }
      componentDidMount(){    
        var responseClone; // 1
         fetch("/api/cards/100")
          .then(function (response) {
          responseClone = response.clone(); // 2
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {    
          this.setState (
          {
            postcards: data
          })
          console.log(data);
    
    }, function (rejectionReason) { // 3
        console.log('Error parsing JSON from response:', rejectionReason, responseClone); // 4
        responseClone.text() // 5
        .then(function (bodyText) {
            console.log('Received the following instead of valid JSON:', bodyText); // 6
        });
      });
        // fetch("/api/cards/100").then ((res) => {return res.json()}).then((data) => 
        // {
        //   this.setState (
        //   {
        //     postcards: data
        //   })
        //   console.log(data);
        // }
        // )    
        // .catch((error) => {
        //   console.log(error);
        // });
    
    } 
  
      render() {
        return (
          <FadeIn>
             <section className="Hol-container">
            <div className="pageStyle">        
              <h1>Real Estate Pre-Printed Postcards</h1>
              <h2>
                Mail 100 pre-printed postcards for just $75, all costs included.
              </h2>
              <p>
                Choose a postcard from our gallery below or create a professional
                custom postcard.
              </p>
              <p>
                Are you a broker? Ask about how we can help your whole office to
                mail pre-printed postcards at a discounted rate.
              </p>
              <p>Pricing: Click here.</p>
              <p>
                Order now:<br></br>
                By phone - 404.849.6139 · By email - info@mrpostcard.com
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="positionImage" >
            {this.state.postcards.map((card) => {
              return <img key={card.id} src={card.image}/>
            })}
            </div>
            </section>
          </FadeIn>
        );
      }
    }
```

below is part of the console to show the error message and part of that index.html file that is being returned:

```
Error parsing JSON from response: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:3458/api/cards/100', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
RealEstate.js:29 Received the following instead of valid JSON: 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
```

this is my database in its current form...in mysql workbench there are not 2 backslashes in my view...not sure why copying it from there shows as 2 backslashes since they are there as escapes in the INSERT so the url would have them

```
    '1', '100', 'C:\\Users\\ceh71\\repos\\final_project\\final_project\\src\\images\\home1.jpg'
    '2', '100', 'C:\\Users\\ceh71\\repos\\final_project\\final_project\\src\\images\\home2.jpg'
    '3', '100', 'C:\\Users\\ceh71\\repos\\final_project\\final_project\\src\\images\\home3.jpg'
    '4', '200', 'C:\\Users\\ceh71\\repos\\final_project\\final_project\\src\\images\\calender1.jpg'
    '5', '200', 'C:\\Users\\ceh71\\repos\\final_project\\final_project\\src\\images\\calender2.jpg'
    '6', '300', 'C:\\Users\\ceh71\\repos\\final_project\\final_project\\src\\images\\sports1.jpg'
    '7', '300', 'C:\\Users\\ceh71\\repos\\final_project\\final_project\\src\\images\\sports2.jpg'
    '8', '300', 'C:\\Users\\ceh71\\repos\\final_project\\final_project\\src\\images\\sports3.jpg'
    '9', '400', 'C:\\Users\\ceh71\\repos\\final_project\\final_project\\src\\images\\holiday1.jpg'
    '10', '400', 'C:\\Users\\ceh71\\repos\\final_project\\final_project\\src\\images\\holiday2.jpg'
    '11', '400', 'C:\\Users\\ceh71\\repos\\final_project\\final_project\\src\\images\\holiday3.jpg'
    '12', '500', 'C:\\Users\\ceh71\\repos\\final_project\\final_project\\src\\images\\business1.jpg'
    '13', '500', 'C:\\Users\\ceh71\\repos\\final_project\\final_project\\src\\images\\business2.jpg'
    '14', '500', 'C:\\Users\\ceh71\\repos\\final_project\\final_project\\src\\images\\business3.jpg'
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I am not sure what needs to be trimmed. it looks like the problem is with the call to the database in the RealEstate.js file but the code looks to be correct. I included all the other database related code in case there was something there that I am doing wrong since they are coupled to the RealEstate.js file. I included the error message I got in the console in case that may be familiar to someone and they may have had the same message.